# C++ не открывается файл в Windows 10

Tags: файлы, visual-c++, windows-10

Следующий код для проверки наличия файла в директории sPath с именем sFileName и любым расширением работает в Windows 7 и не работает в Windows 10

```
 if ( Directory::Exists( sPath_upd ) )
                        {  
                            if (File::Exists(sPath_upd + sFileName + ".*")) return *result = 1;
                            else return *result = 0;
                        }   
                        else return *result = 0;
```

Comment: А какая-то ошибка вываливается? Или просто не работает?

Comment: Вероятно на десятке нет прав на доступ к папке. А исключение глотается где-то выше.

Comment: Доступ к папке есть, так как вываливается в точке   if (File::Exists(sPath_upd + sFileName + ".*")). Неизвестная системная ошибка.